# Variables Pointing To The Same Function

Tags: javascript

I have created a new variable, `carBasket` and `foodBasket`, and set them equal to the `basketModule()` function. They however are pointed to the same function when I want each of these two variables pointed to their own function. I am wondering what should I be doing to achieve this?

```
var basketModule = (function() {
    var basket = [];
    return {
        addItem: function(values) {
            basket.push(values);
        },
        getItemCount: function() {
            return basket.length;
        }
    };
}());

carBasket = basketModule;
carBasket.addItem('Audi');

foodBasket = basketModule;
foodBasket.addItem('Ham');

foodBasket.getItemCount(); //outputs 2 instead of 1
```

Comment: Assigning object references does not result in objects being copied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must call a function for each object in order to generate different variables for each one, e.g:

```
var basketModule = function() {
  var basket = [];
  return {
    addItem: function(values) {
      basket.push(values);
    },
    getItemCount: function() {
      return basket.length;
    }
  };
};
var carBasket = basketModule(),
    foodBasket = basketModule();
carBasket.addItem('Audi');
foodBasket.addItem('Ham');
foodBasket.getItemCount(); // 1
```

However, in order to reuse the methods for all instances, better use a constructor:

```
var BasketModule = function() {
  this.basket = [];
};
BasketModule.prototype.addItem = function(values) {
  this.basket.push(values);
};
BasketModule.prototype.getItemCount = function() {
  return this.basket.length;
};
var carBasket = new BasketModule(),
    foodBasket = new BasketModule();
carBasket.addItem('Audi');
foodBasket.addItem('Ham');
foodBasket.getItemCount(); // 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you using a `prototype` to conserve memory?

Comment: @Jon Yes, this way I only define the methods in the prototype only once, and all instances use those. In the first code each basket has its own copy of the methods.

Comment: This works. But I was wondering though, isn't it a better practice to create an object with a constructor and properties instead of the function in the first place?

Comment: @el3ati2 The first code (function) is the working code closest to OP's one. The second code (constructor) is how I would recommend to do it.

Comment: You updated your answer as I was writing my comment :)

Comment: @Oriol In your first block if code, you did not have to use `new` when assigning carBasket to basketModule(). In your second block of text, you used `new`. Why is that?

Comment: @Jon Because in the first one I'm just calling a function which returns some value. In the second one, I'm instantiating a constructor. Simplifying, that creates an object which inherits from `BasketModule.prototype`, calls `BasketModule` passing that object as the `this` value, and returns the object.

Comment: @Oriol Ahh, got'cha. That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider trying this pattern instead:

```
var BasketModule = function() {
    var basket = [];
    return {
        addItem: function(values) {
            basket.push(values);
        },
        getItemCount: function() {
            return basket.length;
        }
    };
};

carBasket = new BasketModule();
carBasket.addItem('Audi');

foodBasket = new BasketModule();
foodBasket.addItem('Ham');
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nvsbjset/

This will create separate objects for each `basket`